# how to validate two picklist values are same

Tags: validation

I have this validation rule that will prevent two pick list field values from being the same. That means if both fields are empty it is also firing, but that shouldn't happen.

```
And(IF( ( TEXT(Mkts_Region__c) = TEXT(Mkts_Sharing_Region__c)) , true, false))
```

Please guide me how to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just need to check that the fields are not blank:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Mkts_Region__c)) && (TEXT(Mkts_Region__c) == TEXT(Mkts_Sharing_Region__c))
```

Also, you don't need the `IF`, and using `&&` can often make things easier to read than `AND()`