# Opportunity Conditional Automation

Tags: validation, opportunity, conditional

I'm really unsure how to go about the following validation rule based on a certain condition. My issue is, If Sole Proprietor is selected from the Win Reason  drop-down, i.e. ISPICKVAL(Win Reason, "No Competition/Sole Source"), select the same value "No Competition/Sole Source" from the Competitor pick-list on the Opportunity page. Is this feasible just with some validation, or is there more to it?

Thanks is adavance!

Comment: did you try the validation rule approach and it didn't work?

Comment: I haven't, because I'm not sure how to tell it to pick the same value for a different field. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: did you look at this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45515/how-to-validate-two-picklist-values-are-same ? asked today, no less

Comment: That does seem like the likely answer to this, thanks! But I'm curious, is there any way to automate this to select the value from a pick-list for the user based on their first pick from the drop-down before clicking the 'submit' button?

Comment: Ah, cancel this. I talked to my administrator and I just need to create a workflow rule! Thanks for your help!

Comment: ah, i misunderstood - I thought you wanted to force the user to enter the same value in two picklists; yes, you can use workflow to sync the value from fieldA to fieldB.

Comment: The workflow didn't work!:( I just need some validation to check and make sure IF Win Reason = "No Competition/Sole Source" then validate that a multi-picklist equals the same value ("No Competition/Sole Source"). Right now the only way it's validating is if "No Competition/Sole Source" is ALREADY picked in the multi-picklist, with this code-    AND(ISPICKVAL(Win_Reason__c, "No Competition/Sole Source") ,
INCLUDES(Competitor_s__c, "No Competitor/Sole Source")) Any clue how to do this through validation?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the validation rule as you wrote in the comment:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Win_Reason__c,  "No Competition/Sole Source") , 
    INCLUDES(Competitor_s__c, "No Competitor/Sole Source")
)
```

Assuming that `No Competitor/Sole Source` in the multi-select picklist is a typo and should be, as per your original post be:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Win_Reason__c,  "No Competition/Sole Source") , 
    INCLUDES(Competitor_s__c, "No Competition/Sole Source")
)
```

Then that rule will be true if both picklists have the same value and thus fire an error.

Since you want the VR to fire if both picklists are not the same:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Win_Reason__c, "No Competition/Sole Source") , 
    OR(
       NOT(INCLUDES(Competitor_s__c, "No Competitor/Sole Source"),
       ISBLANK(Competitor_s__c)
       )
)
```